# IBM MQ Message copy to a new queue

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I have requirement to copy the message in real time from one queue to another for a specific period of time. How can we configure this ? Manual switch is possible with IBM MQ.
use case is like ..
My primary queue connected to primary application.
when primary application goes down i need to process the data through secondary application using a secondary queue.
once primary application is up , then it will pick the data from primary queue and re process it .

So here the MQ switch should replicate/copy the data from primary to secondary queue in the down time. so that secondary app can do the processing.

I have gone through the docs and understand that replication is possible but not sure how to do with manual switch (ON / OFF) for a specific period.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You have tagged this question with activemq as well as ibm-mq. Is there an activemq component in your question that you should mention? If not, and this is purely IBM MQ, then sure you can have an application that reads messages from one queue and writes them to another queue. Your question includes the phrase "for a specific period of time". Could you elaborate on what that means? Do you only need the copying to happen between certain hours?

Comment: Is this reheated to Active MQ in some way or just IBM MQ? Can you edit and describe the usecase more.   Do you want a copy of messages in real time to a second queue in addition to the application being able to read the message from the original queue?

Comment: sorry i have removed active MQ tag . 
Yes Morgan and Josh .I want it for certain hours only . This feature i should be able to control likee a switch in production environment. If i make it on then message should copy to my new queue.

Comment: I still don't understand the use case.  Will messages just accumulate on the 1st queue and then you want to move them to a 2nd?  Please edit your question and describe in much more detail than you have.   Also provide details of what you have tried or researched already.

Comment: updated the description with details .. kindly check

Comment: Do you need MQMD replicated or just the message body?

Comment: we need both MQMD and msg body

Comment: There is no feature of IBM MQ that works in the manner you describe.  The closest thing built into IBM MQ would be the `dmpmqmsg` utility that comes with MQ v8.0 and later to "copy" messages to a 2nd queue, but you would then need to figure out how to copy only new messages from that queue.  Another possibility would be to move the messages from the 1st queue and put a copy in 2 more queues, one of those would be read by your secondary app, the other could be used to copy the messages back to the primary queue when your app is back up, this would only work if order didn't matter.

Comment: outside of MQ there are products that replicate messages, but I'm not familiar with the details of these and how they could be turned on and off on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is for MQ to know about your application infrastructure.  That's not possible.

Solution #1:

Why don't you copy/replicate all messages to a secondary queue, then have your secondary application ONLY process messages IF the IPPROCS of the primary queue is ZERO.  As soon as IPPROCS of the primary queue is NOT zero then discard messages in the secondary queue.

Solution #2:

Create a third application that monitors the IPPROCS of the primary queue.  When it is ZERO, start copying the messages to the secondary queue.  Note: When the third application has the primary queue opened, IPPROCS wiil be 1.  Hence, when the IPPROCS of the primary queue is 2 (or greater) then stop copying the messages and close the primary queue.

Solution #3:

Would involve a 3rd party solution.  You could use [MQ Message Replication](https://capitalware.com/mqmr_overview.html) (MQMR) to copy/replicate the messages in the primary queue to the secondary queue. Configure MQMR as needed but set it to inactive.  When the primary application goes down/offline then immediately change MQMR to active. When the primary application is up and running again switch MQMR back to inactive.

Solution 4:

This solution is a combination of solution #1 and #3.  Use [MQMR](https://capitalware.com/mqmr_overview.html)  to copy/replicate all messages in the primary queue to the secondary queue. Have your secondary application ONLY process messages IF the IPPROCS of the primary queue is ZERO. As soon as IPPROCS of the primary queue is NOT zero then discard messages in the secondary queue.

Comment: Thank you Roger .. let me check these options